# Accessing inner scope variable values on the page with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, variables, casperjs

I'm new to CasperJS and trying to get some JS code from a website. Let's say I got this code:

```
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = "true";

    function abc(){
        var b = "someValue";
        b = b + " and other value";
    }
</script>
...
...
</html>
```

I'm able to get 'a' value by using:

```
casper.getGlobal("a");
```

But can't find the way to get 'b' value (if it's possible). I'm thinking of downloading whole page and then parsing it offline but maybe someone knows a better way to take advantage of CasperJS.

Comment: There's no direct way to access `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has function level scope. It means that variable defined inside of a function with the `var` or `let` keywords are local. You can't access them from an outer scope. This would be quite strange if you could, since that would mean that the function was is in some kind of suspended execution state. There is no direct way to access `b`.

You're correct to suggest that you will need to parse the function somehow to retrieve that value. It seems that the function that contains the interesting value is defined globally, so you can access that function object.

You could for example remove all the things that make this `abc` function a function and `eval` it. That would enable you to directly access `b`.

Semi-pseudo code:

```
var b = casper.evaluate(function(){
    var abcFnString = abc.toString()
        .replace("function abc(){", "") // remove header
        .replace(/return/g, "")         // remove returns
        .slice(0, -1);                  // removed footer
    return (function(){
        eval(abcFnString);
        return b;
    })();
});
```